# ReactJS Giving An Unexpected Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, key, warnings, listitem

It's a beautiful day but this thing is blocking my view:
[image]

I've tried everything (except asking a question ._.) and searched everywhere. But the expected result could not be obtained :'(
So, this is my code where I think the error is happening:

```
           <div className="mt-3">
              {data.activities?.map((act) => {
                return <Chip className="mr-2 px-3" label={act} key={act.id} />;
              })}
           </div>{" "}
```

Well it's a part of my file `packageCard.js` but if you want the whole file here it is:

```
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Clock from "./img/main_page_icons/clock.svg";
import Person from "./img/main_page_icons/person.svg";
import MapPin from "./img/main_page_icons/map-pin.svg";
import Package1 from "./img/main_page/package 1.png";

function PackageCard({ data }) {
console.log(data);
return (
<>
  <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 card-super-container">
    <div className="card-container">
      <div className="card-image-wrapper">
        <div>
          <div className="card-image-background">
            <img
              alt="package 1"
              src={data.featuredImg}
              style={{ borderRadius: "6px" }}
              className="w-100 "
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="card-details-container">
        <span className="text-bold details-container-header">
          {data.name}
        </span>
        <div>
          <div className="card-details-text">
            <div>{data.description}</div>
            <div>
              <h6 className="card-price">{`Price: ${data.price} USD`}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="card-final-desc">
          <div className="card-final-desc-item">
            <span className="card-dot"></span>
            <img alt="clock" src={Clock} className="mr-1" />
            {` ${data.days}D / ${data.nights}N `}
          </div>
          <div className="card-final-desc-item">
            <span className="card-dot"></span>
            <img alt="clock" src={Person} className="mr-1" />
            {` ${data.noOfPersons} Person `}
          </div>
          <div className="card-final-desc-item">
            <span className="card-dot"></span>
            <img alt="clock" src={MapPin} className="mr-1" />
            {` ${data.destination} `}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="card-btn-container">
        <button className="btn  zoki-btn">Book Now </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="col-lg-4 mb-4">
    <img
      alt="package 1"
      src={data.featuredImg}
      style={{ height: 250 }}
      className="w-100"
    />
    <div
      className="bg-white py-4 px-4 shadow-lg"
      style={{ fontSize: 14, textAlign: "start" }}
    >
      <h6>{data.name}</h6>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
        <h6 className="m-0">{`Price: ${data.price} USD`}</h6>
        <h6 className="m-0" style={{ color: "#9C8E35", cursor: "pointer" }}>
          Book Now
        </h6>
      </div>
      /!*{" "}
      <div className="mt-3">
        {data.activities?.map((act) => {
          return <Chip className="mr-2 px-3" label={act} key={act.id} />;
        })}
      </div>{" "}
      *!/
    </div>
    <div
      className="row shadow mx-3"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#9C8E35", fontSize: 12 }}
    >
      <div className="col-4 p-0 text-center">
        <div
          className="py-2 text-white d-flex w-100 justify-content-center"
          style={{ borderRight: "1px solid white" }}
        >
          <img alt="clock" src={Clock} className="mr-1" />
          <p className="mb-0">{` ${data.days} D / ${data.nights} N `}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-4 p-0">
        <div
          className="py-2 text-white d-flex w-100 justify-content-center"
          style={{ borderRight: "1px solid white" }}
        >
          <img alt="clock" src={Person} className="mr-1" />
          <p className="mb-0">{` ${data.noOfPersons} Person `}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-4 p-0">
        <div className="py-2 text-white d-flex w-100 justify-content-center">
          <img alt="clock" src={MapPin} className="mr-1" />
          <p className="mb-0">{` ${data.destination} `}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
 );
 }

 export default PackageCard;
```

Packages.js Component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getAvailablePackages } from "crud";
import PackageBg from "../../../assets/img/offers.jpg";
import Card from "./packageCard";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Packages() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [listPackages, setListPackages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = {
      search: { query: "" },
      sort: "name",
      page: 1,
      pageSize: 3,
    };
    setLoading(true);
    getAvailablePackages(params)
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res.data.data)
        setListPackages(res.data.data.travelPackages);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
  let checkData = [
    {
      name: "ahmad",
      description: "this is description",
      price: 5,
      days: 5,
      nights: 9,
      noOfPersons: 9,
      destination: "England",
      featuredImg:
        "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/castle-combe-in-the-fall-wiltshire-england-picture-id157006201?s=612x612",
    },
    {
      name: "ali",
      description: "this is description",
      price: 5,
      days: 5,
      nights: 9,
      noOfPersons: 9,
      destination: "homeland",
      featuredImg:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538332576228-eb5b4c4de6f5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZmlubGFuZHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80",
    },
    {
      name: "ali",
      description: "this is description",
      price: 5,
      days: 5,
      nights: 9,
      noOfPersons: 9,
      destination: "finland",
      featuredImg:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538332576228-eb5b4c4de6f5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZmlubGFuZHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div
      id="zoki-packages"
      className="text-center py-5 my-5"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${PackageBg})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
      }}
    >
      <div className="container" style={{ color: "#344767" }}>
        <h6 className="text-bold font-italic"> EXPLORE GREAT PLACES </h6>
        <h1 className=""> Popular Packages </h1>
        <div className="row justify-content-center align-content-center">
          {checkData?.map((pkg) => {
            return <Card data={pkg} key={pkg.id} />;
          })}

          {loading ? (
            <CircularProgress className="my-4 ml-auto mr-auto" />
          ) : listPackages.length ? (
            listPackages?.map((pkg) => {
              return <Card data={pkg} key={pkg.id} />;
            })
          ) : (
            <h4 className="my-4 ml-auto mr-auto">
              No Package Available at that time.
            </h4>
          )}
        </div>
        {listPackages.length ? (
          <button
            onClick={() => history.push("/search-packages")}
            className="btn btn-dark px-4 p-2 rounded-pill my-4"
            style={{ color: "#CFBD45", backgroundColor: "black", fontSize: 14 }}
          >
            <p className="mb-0"> VEIW ALL PACKAGES </p>
          </button>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Packages;
```

I will be very grateful if you find a solution. I appreciate any help you can provide <33

Comment: Show the `Packages` component too.

Comment: Are you sure that all `act` have a unique `id`? Maybe try something like `data.activities?.map((act, index) => <Chip className="mr-2 px-3" label={act} key={ act.id + '_' + index } />` see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Hao Wu, I'm sorry but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @Hayaz try to embed `<Chip className="mr-2 px-3" label={act} />` in a `React.Fragment key={act.id}`

Comment: tried that more than 2 times till now still didn't work

Comment: Your objects in `checkData` don't have ids so you can't use that as a key. And what about `listPackages` - do those objects have ids?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `act` does not have a unique id, try using the index of the map.

```js
<div className="mt-3">
  {data.activities?.map((act, i) => (
    <Chip className="mr-2 px-3" label={act} key={i} />
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: I think it only makes the error disappear. [Console Log](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1034028160821497887/1049622325223493663/image.png)  I'm not being able to see the errors but the warnings and info are working. I typed the code you gave in my Packages.js file on lines 83-85 and 90-92:
        ` {checkData?.map((pkg, i) => { return <Card data={pkg} key={i} />; })}`

Answer (score 1):

if you use the `act.id` as the key,should make sure every id is unique cause

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

here is the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)